# Sending and Receiving JSON data from a restful webservice ?

Tags: java, json, web-services, rest

Here is my POJO Code :

```
/*
* To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
* and open the template in the editor.
*/
package com.akapoor.ws.testws.model;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.annotation.ManagedBean;
import javax.ws.rs.WebApplicationException;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;  
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response.Status;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper;
import org.codehaus.jettison.json.JSONObject;

/**
*
* @author
*/
@XmlRootElement(name = "person")
@XmlType(propOrder = {"id", "fullName", "age"})
public class Person{

private int id;
private String fullName;
private int age;

//Must have no-argument constructor
public Person() {
}

public Person(String jsonRepresentation) {
     //Converts Java Object in & From Json
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();//Jackson
    Person object; 

    try {

        /*Deserialisierung
         * JSON Unmarshalling (FROM JSONrepresentation to Object)
         * Converting JSON String 
         */ 
        object = mapper.readValue(jsonRepresentation, Person.class); //Jackson JSON

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).
                entity("Couldn´t parse JSON string: " + e.getMessage()).build());
    }
    this.age = object.getAge();
    this.fullName = object.getFullName();
    this.id = object.getId();
}

/* toPack from String to Object
 * Deserializes an Object of class Person from its JSON representation+
 * Constructor with String Json
 */
// JSON to Person 
public static Person fromString (String jsonRepresentation) {

    //Converts Java Object in & From Json
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();//Jackson
    Person object; 

    try {
        /*Deserialisierung
         * JSON Unmarshalling (FROM JSONrepresentation to Object)
         * Converting JSON String 
         */ 
        object = mapper.readValue(jsonRepresentation, Person.class); //Jackson JSON

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new WebApplicationException(Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST).
                entity("Couldn´t parse JSON string: " + e.getMessage()).build());
    }
    return object; 
}

// Getter & Setter
@XmlElement
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@XmlElement
public String getFullName() {
    return fullName;
}

public void setFullName(String fullName) {
    this.fullName = fullName;
}

@XmlElement
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}
}
```

and my Service look like this:

```
@Path("service")
public class Service {
//GetObject
@POST
@Path("/getObject")
//JSON-Serialisierung --> JSON-serialisiertes Objekt wird vom Browser empfangen
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
//JSON-Deserialisierung
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)  //client sends also JSON
public Person getObjectWithObject(@QueryParam("person") Person person) {

     //Encode a JSON object
    //{"id":1,"fullName":"name","age":22}

    String fullName = person.getFullName();
    int age = person.getAge()``;
    int id = person.getId();

    //Encode a JSON object

    //{"id":1,"fullName":"name","age":22}


    //return Object with details
    return person;
    //return person; 
}
} //End of class Service
```

How I can encode an decode JSON for my Webservice.

I am Using JAX-RS. and want to receive my JSONRespresentation in Browser with a URI like:

Ex :
How will be my URI look like

Help me to respresent JSON using @Produces and @Consumes

Comment: Why use XML annotations if you do JSON?

Comment: XML annotations are used for marshalling and unmarshalling XML and JSON data.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `@QueryParam`, just provide your POJO class like this:

```
@POST
@Path("person")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Person createPerson(Person person) {
    //Process retrieved data
    String name = person.getName();
    return person;
}
```

Marshalling and unmarshalling JSON data will be handled by your framework (e.g. Jersey).

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but how will look like my client ? do i have to write a client ?                                                                                    Can You tell me how my Service (Framework) has to be look like ?

Comment: @user3428776 Writing a client is up to you. You can test it using CURL command line tool, in PHP, or whatever, just make sure to set proper content negotiation headers in each request. You didn't provide any client information, so it is hard to provide an answer to your comment.

Comment: ok how looks the URI like: which i have to call on my browser? i am very confused with the syntax

Comment: if talking about your service class in your question it would be `http://{server_root}/{application_root}/service/getObject`, in my answer I changed it to `http://{server_root}/{application_root}/service/person` as it looks more "RESTy" to me. Any way your implementation now supports only POST request with `Content-Type: application/json` and `Accept: application/json` headers.

Comment: but i am getting http status 405. -.-                                    how can I see a result on my browser.. what i have to change ? where is my mistakes ? sorr, that i am asking again.

Comment: 405 is Method not allowed response code, which should mean that your are not sending POST request. Use e.g. Firefox FireBug plugin, it will show you the request headers. There are many tools for testing web APIs, get some plugin for your browser to take full control of your requests. Just typing the URL in browser is really inefficient here.